# How can I share my wordpress site with a friend?

Tags: plugins, wp-admin, sharing

im using desktop server to host my site and wanted to know how I can share it with a friend. We both want to work on it together. I clicked on add users and created his account, but he didn't get any email. is there a plugin i have to download to do this?

Comment: Here you have a guide to follow: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnS1aNPNuhk

Comment: Using desktop server, you might not share the same login with remote user. But yes, if you are in intranet...you can share with your friend. Otherwise you need to have it hosted on a shared/remote server...

Answer (score 0):

Is the mail configured for your server?

If not or isn't possible, try using an SMTP mail plugin and connect to example gmail, by letting [less secure apps use it](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en). You'll have to configure it in the plugin and on the gmail account also.

But yes, if your server isn't on the same network as your friends computer, you need a remote/shared server.